# Hibernate Bean Validation not available in the class path

Tags: java, hibernate, classpath, bean-validation

I decided to try out Hibernate today, which looks promising, although the setup could be easier. After having found solutions for the first million or so configuration errors I'm now stuck with this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: manager1] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
(...)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Bean Validation not available in the class path but required in javax.persistence.validation.mode
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyHibernateListeners(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 5 more
```

Peristence.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <class>net.zomis.hibernate.Game</class>
      <class>net.zomis.hibernate.TestFields</class>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
      <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE" />  
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The (as far as I can tell) relevant portions of `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        (...)
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" >validate</property>
        <mapping class="net.zomis.hibernate.Game" />
        <mapping class="net.zomis.hibernate.TestFields" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have tried adding [this](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.3.1.Final.jar) to the build path without any change. I have googled for `Bean Validation not available in the class path but required in javax.persistence.validation.mode` and also just `Bean Validation not available in the class path`. I found the source code, but that doesn't help me much.

I have also tried removing the properties from the xml configuration files, without any luck.

I **do not** use Maven. I simply use Eclipse and build and run the project directly from Eclipse.

The obvious question is: How can I solve this problem? Do I need an additional jar in my build path that I have missed? (In that case which one?) and also: Why is it needed? Can I change something so that it is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have the [validation-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA) (there's a download JAR link you can use as you don't use maven) in your classpath.

Hibernate searches for the javax.validation.Validation class in the classpath.
If it doesn't find it it throws the `Bean Validation not available in the class path but required in javax.persistence.validation.mode` error.

- If you're not using maven you need to build up the classpath yourself and it's easy to miss a jar. It might be worthwhile to just use maven to bootstrap your project, and to make sure you have all the jars in place.
- If you're using maven, the validation-api is pulled in as a transitive dependency from hibernate-validator.

Comment: Unless you're using JEE6, then the validation API jar shouldn't be used, as it's bundled.

Comment: Finally that problem is solved. (Surprised I couldn't find a previous question for this) I also found out that I needed this as well: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator  Next project will be to learn Maven I suppose :) ...and then finally understand git :P (although I've used git previously)

Comment: Maven does help you a lot in dealing with these dependency issues. Most frameworks (spring / hibernate / ....) use it so you get an immediate benefit.

Comment: I must say that Maven was a lot easier to setup and use than Hibernate was. Also, my picture about what Maven is turned out to be incorrect - now I know what it is and I love it. For everyone else who wants to get started with Maven and is using Eclipse, use the update site `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases` and you're done !

Answer (score 4):

You need the Hibernate Validator artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This will also include the Bean Validation API, which indeed is in this case a requirement as well.

In case you are not using any Bean Validation constraints (e.g. @NotNull, @Before, @Pattern, etc) you could also just remove

```
<validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
```

or set it to NONE. Bean Validation is not required for Hibernate usage it is just an add-on defined in the JPA specification. If Bean Validation is on the classpath life cycle based validation (validation of entities on pre-update, pre-persist, etc) is automatically enabled (see also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e3096 and of course the JPA 2 specification).

On the other hand, if you don't have Bean Validation on the classpath, but explicitly ask for it via the configuration option in *persistence.xml* you get the error you describe.

Comment: I like how you read through the question... "I **do not** use maven [...]"

Comment: Just because I used a GAV for specifying what you need, I am not implying that you have to use Maven. You can be using whatever, but somehow I need to specify the right artifact. Using the dependency notation is quite useful in this case and not bound to the use of Maven.

Comment: why not instead of that dependency management-specific xml-notation use something like: `org.hibernate.hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar` (which is what you get either way) and that is much more "google-friendly" than the xml?

Comment: @Vogel612 I actually ended up using Maven for Hibernate :)